# Cross Account Template Accessibility

Tags: docusignapi

It appears that it is possible to generate an envelope using a template that does not belong to the account that was authenticated in the REST call. The two accounts were completely unrelated. Access to the generated envelope is limited to the account that generated the envelope; however the access to the template seems to be allowed to any account.

Scenario where this behavior was noticed:
- Account 1 - Created Template #1
- Account 2 - Generate an envelope using Template ID generated by Account 1

I could not find documentation or configuration related to behavior.

I need to confirm if the behavior is intended/supported before we plan to utilize the functionality.

Comment: Where did you first here it's possible to use a template from a different account?  Please post any resources you have on this or the post where you saw that mentioned.

Comment: It was detected by accident during testing. We used one account to create templates and during later stages of testing switched accounts, but never changed the template ids stored in our application. They continued to work even though the new account has no relationship with the other. Strangely the old template ID (from account 1) works in account 2, but not visa versa. Must be some type of defect.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best solution if you want to use Templates from one account in another is to simply move them.  You might only be able to do this in the classic UI so you might have to switch back through your preferences, but you can:

1. Download the actual XML for each template you want to "share" across accounts.
2. Open the second account and select to upload template(s) and chose the XML files you downloaded.

As mentioned you might have to switch back to the classic UI to download/upload, but you definitely will not be able to use Templates from one account when you are an un-authenticated user in another account.